# How to load rss feed from url with jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#success").load("doc.txt", function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

.load("doc.txt" // is in my local
I want get load from url ex: www.example.com/feed

Comment: Why not just substitute `doc.txt` with `www.example.com/feed`?

Comment: I substitute like that. But it not work.